# /select with 'q' parameter does not work

Tags: solr

Whenever i query with q=*:* it shows all the documents but when i query with q=programmer 0 docs found.(contents is the default search field)
my schema has: id(unique),author,title,contents fields
Also query works fine for:
q=author:"Value" or q=title:"my book" etc, only for contents field no results.
Also when i query using spell checker(/spell?q=programmer) output shows spelling suggestions for this word,when 'programmer' is the right word and present in many documents.
I referred the example docs for configurations. 
All of a sudden i am getting this,initially it worked fine.
I guess there some problem only in the contents field,but cannot figure it out.
Is it because indexes are not created properly for contents field?
(I am using solr 4.2 on Windows 7 with tomcat as webserver)
Please help.Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you set the default search field? The reason you have this problem might be because you didn't set the `<defaultSearchField>` field in your schema.xml file. This is why "q=author:value" works while q=WHATEVER doesn't.

> The  Is used by Solr when parsing queries to
>   identify which field name should be searched in queries where an
>   explicit field name has not been used.

But also consider this:

> The  is used by Solr when parsing queries to
>   identify which field name should be searched in queries where an
>   explicit field name has not been used. It is preferable to not use or
>   rely on this setting; instead the request handler or query LocalParams
>   for a search should specify the default field(s) to search on. This
>   setting here can be omitted and it is being considered for
>   deprecation.

Comment: <defaultSearchField>contents</defaultSearchField> here i did add it, n also query like:http://localhost:8080/solr/document/select?q=contents:for returns 0 records.

Comment: are you sure schema field is configured correctly? Try adding parenthesis around "for"? Also, try setting the default field to another field and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any data in your instance. try q=*:* and see what it returns. "for" is a stop word, may be it was filtered out. Look for something else as value to test.